# vs code wont run the code although there is no bugs

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

i tried to run this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bardAIcalc {

    private Frame frame;
    private Label label1, label2, label3;
    private TextField textField1, textField2;
    private Button button1, button2, button3, button4;
    private TextField textField3;

    public void BardAIcalc() {

        frame = new Frame("Calculator");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));

        label1 = new Label("Number 1:");
        label2 = new Label("Number 2:");
        label3 = new Label("Result:");

        textField1 = new TextField();
        textField2 = new TextField();
        textField3 = new TextField();
        button1 = new Button("+");
        button2 = new Button("-");
        button3 = new Button("Clear");
        button4 = new Button("Exit");

        frame.add(label1);
        frame.add(textField1);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.add(textField2);
        frame.add(label3);
        frame.add(textField3);
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(button3);
        frame.add(button4);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String number1 = textField1.getText();
                String number2 = textField2.getText();

                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1);
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2);

                int result = num1 + num2;

                textField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String number1 = textField1.getText();
                String number2 = textField2.getText();

                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1);
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2);

                int result = num1 - num2;

                textField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            }
        });

        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textField1.setText("");
                textField2.setText("");
                textField3.setText("");
            }
        });

        button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new bardAIcalc();
    }
}
```

and vs code keeps acts like it will run but after waiting nothing happens
it never happend before
and any other code run smoothly but this one wont run

i tried:

> deleting the file and creat a new one

> installing a fresh version of JRE

but vs code still wont run the code and the code doesnt have any bugs

Comment: How do you know that the code isn't running? Do you have a println in the main method that shows that nothing is being printed? I suggest that you do this.

Comment: Hint: the GUI won't display if you don't make it visible. There is no compilation bug, but your code has a huge logic bug, and those are harder to debug.

Comment: ok, yes it's running but the GUI is not appearing @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes its running , should i wait for the GUI to display?

Comment: You have a "pseudo" constructor: `public void BardAIcalc() { ... }`, and this is not being called. Get rid of the `void` return type since constructors should have no return type.

Comment: But having said that, whoever or whatever is suggesting that you learn how to use the AWT GUI library is doing you a grave disservice. Much better to learn a GUI library that is still being supported, not one that has been superseded 20+ years ago.